# Umbraco Culture different when published

Tags: umbraco, culture

Locally Umbraco Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name returns "en-GB".

When Published it returns "en-US" using the same database.

I've set Umbraco > Settings > Language > Culture Name to English(United Kingdom)

It's hosted on a Azure App Service

Answer (score 1):

A friend helped and I've added the cultures to the web.config.
Both Local and Server are the same now.

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <globalization  culture="en-GB" uiCulture="en-GB"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try going to your root node of your site, right click it and select *Culture and Hostname*.

You should see a dropdown being set to `inherit`. Change this to `en-GB` and hit save. Then do the same and change it back to `inherit`.

This sometimes acts up and it doesn't refresh the setting on the node when you have tried applying a different culture.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't seem to work. It was just being ignored no matter what I set It to.

Comment: That's a bit strange .. it works for me here on local and when deploying to a remote - but good to hear that you got it resolved in a different way!